# Count Unique Identifiers by a result in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to return some values in SQL. Let's call `Column A` as `UniqueIdentifier` I then have a row that lists two different actions that can be done to this unique identifier, let's call the column `action` and the actions `a` and `b`

The actions can be duplicated more than one time per unique identifier, thus listing tons of duplicated `UniqueIdentifier`

How do I get the count of `UniqueIdentifier` where action `a` has been performed and the count where action `a` has not?

I did create a really long and cumbersome way(listed below) using temp tables but I feel like there must be a more roundabout way

```
<!-- language: lang-sql -->
select
UniqueIdentifier
,case when action = 'a' then 1 else 0 end [actionflag]
into #actionflags
from mydatabase


select
distinct UniqueIdentifier
,sum(actionflag)
into #actionflagscount
from #actionflags
group by UniqueIdentifier


select case when actionflag > 0 then 1 else 0 end [actionflag]
,count(uniqueidentifier)
from #actionflagscount
group by case when actionflag > 0 then 1 else 0 end
```

Comment: Can you post the table's (`database`?) definition? It does not feel `UniqueIdentifier` is unique here, but perhaps `(UniqueIdentifier, action)` would be. Also, can you specify the DBMS you are using?

Comment: unique identifier is unique but it duplicates because the action can be done to it more than once, IE, 30 different a actions to one uniqueidentifier

I am using SQL Server 2014 i thnk

Comment: That's basically what I call **not** unique. Please, I really need the info, post the table's definition

Comment: you could think of my table as sort of an activity log, where the unique identifier can have the action performed multiple times at different times and it then gets recorded.

Comment: What you will need to do in the future is post the `create table` in your question. It is crucial for lots of contributors here to know exactly the constraints applied on a table, even if it is just a test case you are building, rather than **your potentially incorrect understanding of** the constraints. Anyway, I have tried giving an answer myself based on what I understood, see if it covers what you want to get.

Comment: Thanks, I will include that in future

Answer (score 0):

Do you want `DISTINCT` ?

```
select case when actionflag > 0 then 1 else 0 end [actionflag],
       count(distinct uniqueidentifier)
from #actionflagscount
group by case when actionflag > 0 then 1 else 0 end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp

CREATE TABLE #temp ([UniqueIdentifier] INT, Action NVARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO #temp ([UniqueIdentifier], Action) VALUES (1, 'a')
INSERT INTO #temp ([UniqueIdentifier], Action) VALUES (2, 'a')
INSERT INTO #temp ([UniqueIdentifier], Action) VALUES (3, 'a')
INSERT INTO #temp ([UniqueIdentifier], Action) VALUES (4, 'b')
INSERT INTO #temp ([UniqueIdentifier], Action) VALUES (5, 'b')
INSERT INTO #temp ([UniqueIdentifier], Action) VALUES (6, 'c')
INSERT INTO #temp ([UniqueIdentifier], Action) VALUES (7, 'c')

SELECT CASE WHEN Action = 'a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ActionFlag, COUNT(*)
FROM #temp
GROUP BY CASE WHEN Action = 'a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

-- Results:
-- ActionFlag   (No column name)
-- 0    4
-- 1    3
```

Comment: I changed the number 6 to 1 to more represent my quandry since this table is basically an activity log and I just want a record of how many ui's have had a on them and how many have not. when I change you 6 to a 1 and the corresponding c to an a I get 4 of the 1 action flags

Answer (score 0):

Considering you may have:

- The same `action` performed several times on the same `UniqueIdentifier`
- Different `action`s performed on the same `UniqueIdentifier`

I would do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT UniqueIdentifier, CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyDatabase WHERE action = 'a' and UniqueIdentifier = MDB.UniqueIdentifier) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ActionPerformed
FROM MyDatabase MDB
```

If this looks fine, then, a simple `COUNT` will do the trick surrounding the previous query.

```
SELECT Count(*), ActionPerformed
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT UniqueIdentifier, CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyDatabase WHERE action = 'a' and UniqueIdentifier = MDB.UniqueIdentifier) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ActionPerformed
    FROM MyDatabase MDB
) T
GROUP BY ActionPerformed
```

`ActionPerformed = 1` means `action` a was performed (possibly `action` b was performed too on the same `UniqueIdentifier`). `ActionPerformed = 0` means `action` a was not performed (but it does not say anything about `action` b)

Answer (score 0):

I would use two levels of aggregation:

```
select sum(case when num_as > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as num_with_as,
       sum(case when num_as = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as num_without_as
from (select uniqueidentifier,
             sum(case when action = 'a' then 1 else 0 end) as num_as
      from mydatabase
      group by uniqueidentifier
     ) d;
```

The inner query counts the number of "a"s per `uniqueidentifier`.  The outer query uses this to get the two values you want.